# Michal childless or have 5 sons?

Tags: contradiction, kjv, 2-samuel, samuel

Was Michal childless or did Michal have 5 sons? I am getting different answers from

- 2 Samuel 6:23
- 2 Samuel 21:8

> 2 Samuel 6:23. Therefore Michal the daughter of Saul had no child unto
> the day of her death.

---

> 2 Samuel 21:8. But the king took the two sons of Rizpah the daughter
> of Aiah, whom she bare unto Saul, Armoni and Mephibosheth; and the
> five sons of Michal the daughter of Saul, whom she brought up for
> Adriel the son of Barzillai the Meholathite:

Both taken from biblegateway.com